# Render string to Razor View

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I'm doing small tests for a project I will develop on .net7. I need your support on something. What I want to do is this;

I want to dynamically compile my view records in a table in my database as a view at runtime; It will be something like this;

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
 {
     //This will come from DB.
     var cshtmlContent = @"
         <div>@Model.Name </div>;
         @if (1=1) {
             <span>1</span>
         }
      """;

     // Here I need to render the razor code from DB. But the critical point here is this; There will not be a physical view file (.cshtml). I need to press the screen without needing this. There will be no physical cshtml files in the application. I will manage all (including _layaout.cshtml) on the database
     return View(cshtmlContent);
 }
```

I hope I was able to explain what I wanted to do. I wonder if there is a way to do this; Can you guide me or make a small example if possible?

Comment: do you have any update on it?

Comment: This article was exactly what I wanted... It turned out to be a cleaner solution than I thought.

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/301/loading-asp-net-core-mvc-views-from-a-database-or-other-location

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround using `@Html.Raw()` which is suitable for simple html content.

```
public IActionResult DynamicContent() {
    ViewBag.content = @"<div>
                            <p>this is the main content stored in database</p>
                            <div class='myclass'>
                                <label>name<lable>
                                <input type='text' />
                            </div>
                        </div>";
    return View();
}

<div>
    hello this is the main content
    @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.content)
</div>
```

[image]

but it only support simple html content.

[image]